# Fire an event after click, Datepicker bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using [datepicker bootstrap 3](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/). I want to fire another event when I select a date.

My code:

```
$('td.day').click(function(){
    alert("It's Not work")
})
```

```html
<tr>
    <td class="day">8</td>
    <td class="day">9</td>
    <td class="day">10</td>
    <td class="day">11</td>
    <td class="day">12</td>
    <td class="disabled day">13</td>
    <td class="disabled day">14</td>
</tr>
```

a demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuG6C/832/)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan. Oh ok. Dint get that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap datepicker raises a `changeDate` event when a selection is made. You can use `on` to hook to that:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    startDate: "auto",
    todayHighlight: true
}).on('changeDate', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tuG6C/834/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [changeDate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html#changedate) event.

```
$(".datepicker").on("changeDate", function(event) {
     alert("test");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tuG6C/833/)